# apostrophe is showing before number in excel when I export the data

Tags: reactjs, excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Dri.png)
I have used useLazyquery to fetch the data from backend

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMx7N.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Dri.png)

[excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPQic.png)

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

Cell text starting with an apostrophe is considered text, not a number. This can be useful for phone numbers where occasionally `+-/` may be used. Normally the apostrophe is not shown. So the writer wanted to use the cell as *text*.

Comment: can we remove that apostrophe after fetching data from backend

Comment: You could try retype number data from backend. `Number(variable)`.

Comment: Use `blob = blob.replaceAll('\'', '');` or something more specifc. (Dangerous, Elo's proposal is better.